# I can print the response but not get the individual values SwiftUI from API get request

Tags: json, swift, rest, swiftui

I am trying to use the spoonacular API to get recipes from this online database API. At the moment I am able to print the response; I will only show a few, as it is fairly long:

```
[Result]: success(<__NSArrayI 0x600000775e60>(
{
    calories = 148;
    carbs = 27g;
    fat = 3g;
    id = 634141;
    image = "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/634141-312x231.jpg";
    imageType = jpg;
    protein = 4g;
    title = "Banana Oatmeal Breakfast Muffins";
},
{
    calories = 150;
    carbs = 22g;
    fat = 3g;
    id = 657359;
    image = "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/657359-312x231.jpg";
    imageType = jpg;
    protein = 10g;
    title = "Pumpkin Pie Smoothie";
}
)

)
```

My fetch function is as follows:

```
func loadData2() {
        
        
        AF.request("https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByNutrients?apiKey=\(apiKey)&minCarbs=10&maxCarbs=50&number=2").responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            
            if let data = response.data
            {

            if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([RecipieAPI].self, from: data) {
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            self.results = response
                                        }
                return
            }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

And I am trying to create a list in my view to test it, but I am unable to fetch the items appropriately:

```
var body: some View {
      
        
        List(results, id: \.id) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(item.title)
                    }
                }.onAppear(perform: loadData2)
        
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Edit** I've realized I am not successfully getting the response, but insead getting the following error:

```
nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
```

Comment: Do you know that your decoding works? Using try? is not a good solution when downloading from an external source. Remove the ? and use a do/catch and do `print(error)` in the catch clause

Comment: I've had a look online, how to use the do catch clause, but I am really struggling to get it to work / understand the concept